# Debugging a VC++ 6 Project in Visual Studio 10

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging, visual-c++-6

I am new to Visual Studio. I have Visual Studio 2010 and Windows 7. I recently checked out a Visual C++ Project. The project was originally a VC++ 6 Project, but a general VC++ Project is available to open with the project that I checked out, so I open the VC++ Project to work with.

When I try to debug the project, none of my breakpoints are hit and the Disassembly window comes up instead. The breakpoints have the error: "Breakpoints will not currently be hit. No symbols loaded for this document."

I have researched this error and fruitlessly tried many things, but I'm wondering if there is something simple I am missing about working in VS10 with a project written in a different version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you build the project with VC 2010? The debugger symbol table from VC6 is not used by VC 2010. So you will have to convert the project and build it in VC 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you 'Rebuild' to ensure your binaries are fresh before you start the debug session. If you get build errors, you will need to fix the code or project settings.

[Added]
Make sure you're building and debugging a Debug build configuration. A Release build usually won't include debug information.

If you have VC 6 available, you could instead install VC6 and [Daffodil](http://daffodil.codeplex.com), then set the project's Platform Target to v60. This way you're building with VC6 build tools, thus minimizing the need for code changes.

Comment: When I try to build the project, I am getting almost 1000 syntax errors which start with `error C2371: 'WCHAR': redefinition; different basic types` and it refers to line 39 `typedef char DBCHAR;` in srv.h; I don't understand why it's complaining about Microsoft's code, do I possibly have a setting wrong?

Comment: The problem is in your code or project settings. You'll need to start there. You can't debug until you can build without errors.